# My MongoDB .find() method is returning null even thought the data exists

Tags: java, database, mongodb, minecraft

I am trying to find a user's UUID in my database, but it's returning null for no reason. It's in the connect() method. I can find this manually, and in my project in javaScript. But for some reason, I'm getting this error.

```
public final class DiscordLink extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
public MongoCollection<Document> users;
public MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        System.setProperty("DEBUG.GO", "true");
        System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "true");
        Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
        mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        connect();

        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[DiscordLink] Plugin enabled...");

        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[DiscordLink] Plugin disabled...");
    }

    public void connect() {
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("MONGOURI");
        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("myFirstDatabase");
        MongoCollection<Document> users = mongoDatabase.getCollection("users");
        Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[DiscordLink] Connected to database!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Document document = users.find(Filters.eq("mcUUID", player.getUniqueId().toString())).first();
        if(document != null) {
            player.kickPlayer(ChatColor.RED + "Discord Authentication Failed!");
        } else { return; }
```

Error:

```
[15:43:01 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to DiscordLink v1.0-SNAPSHOT
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.find(org.bson.conversions.Bson)" because "this.users" is null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding NullPointerException in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-nullpointerexception-in-java)

Comment: Woudn't declaring `MongoCollection<Document> users` inside the `connect` function mask the class property?  Does it behave the same if you start that line with `users = `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `connect` method, you are declaring the field `MongoCollection<Document> users`.

If you IDE is well configurated, it should tell you that this field is not used. Here, you are creating a local field (that keep only in the method scope) instead of setting the global field, which is declared just below the `public final class DiscordLink`.

To fix it, do like this :

```
this.mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("myFirstDatabase")
this.users = this.mongoDatabase.getCollection("users");
```

Here, the `this` key-word is to say you are looking for the global variable, declared outside of the method.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting now `Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase.getCollection(String)" because "this.mongoDatabase" is null`

Comment: I just edit my answer. That's exactly the same problem, So you can apply same suggestion to the mongoDatabase object